# Series expansion of an inverse

Tags: series-expansion, calculus-and-analysis

I have to find the series expansion of the inverse function of : $\arctan\left(\frac{\ln(1+x)}{1+x}\right)$

How do I find out the series expansion of any inverse ?

Note: The inverse of a function $f$ is the unique function $f^{-1}$ that verifies $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ (given $f$ is a bijection)

Comment: Mathematica does not have a built-in function named Reciprocal.

Comment: Additionally such a function $f^{-1}$ need not be unique. For instance, consider $f: x \mapsto x^2$. Then two functions $g_+: y \mapsto \sqrt{y}$ and $g_-: y \mapsto -\sqrt{y}$ both verify $f(g_\pm(y)) = y$.

Comment: Note that the term [reciprocal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal) normally refers to the multiplicative inverse and never the inverse function. This is despite the sometimes confusing notation $f(x)^{-1} \neq f^{-1}(x)$. Maybe you should rewrite this question to avoid confusion.

Comment: I find it strange that the `Series[InverseFunction[ArcTan[Log[1 + #]/(1 + #)] &][x], {x,0,3}]` approach does not work.

Comment: Simon is right, this really should be changed to say "inverse" rather than "reciprocal" as it will confuse a lot of people otherwise.

Comment: I'm editing but that's why I wrote the note to explain !

Comment: Series expansions are local beings. So multivalued inverse "functions" are not an issue, provided one does not expand at a branch point.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is [`InverseSeries`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InverseSeries.html) what you are looking for?

```
InverseSeries[Series[ArcTan[Log[1 + x]/(1 + x)], {x, 0, 5}]]
(*
x+(3 x^2)/2+3 x^3+(149 x^4)/24+(68 x^5)/5+O[x]^6
*)
```

EDIT: looks reasonable:

```
Plot[{
  pl[x],
  invs
  },
 {x, -.3, .3},
 PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Black}, Red}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Who knows what the radius of convergence is, though.

Comment: It works, thank you !

Comment: The function was present since version 1 and a managed to miss it all the time.

Comment: @acl Radius is infinite because it's only a truncated approximation to the actual function. Even if the function itself has an inverse series everywhere convergent, the (polynomial) approximation will still go astray sooner or later. Often enough Pade approximations are better in that respect.

Comment: @Daniel Maybe I am being thick, but I am not sure I can parse what you are saying. Do you mean that since this thing is reverting a series, it's the polynomial approximation to the series that messes up things rather than convergence? Or something else? Sorry, I am knocked out from a day full of bureaucracy and could be talking nonsense.

Comment: I mean that regardless of whether the thing has a convergent series, (i) we are getting a polynomial approx (and that converges everywhere), and (ii) Unless the thing being approximated is also a polynomial, the approximation cannot be good everywhere (again, regardless of whether the infinite series is or is not everywhere convergent), only in some limited range.

Comment: @Daniel right, so your point is that this is not a series but a polynomial?

Comment: The inverse series of a function might have behavior quite different from the series it was derived from; e.g. having a finite radius of convergence when the starting function was convergent everywhere. Padé approximants might allow for analytically continuing a series with finite radius of convergence, but it's no panacea (and even then, there might be other, better transformstions).

Comment: The results of `Plot[Evaluate[Table[Normal[InverseSeries[Series[ArcTan[Log[1 + x]/(1 + x)], {x, 0, k}]]], {k, 25}]], {x, -2, 2}]` would have me conjecture that the radius of convergence is $1$, however.

Comment: @J.M. try `ListPlot[(N[#1[[2]]]/#1[[1]] & ) /@Rest[Partition[CoefficientList[Normal[InverseSeries[Series[ArcTan[Log[1 + x]/(1 + x)], {x, 0, 50}]]], x], 2,1]]]`. Proves nothing though

Comment: I'd have used the `Ratios[]` function myself. ;) Anyway, it does seem to corroborate the finite radius of convergence.

Comment: @J.M. had never heard of the `Ratios` function either!

Answer (score 14):

Had `InverseSeries[]` not been a built-in function, one option might be to invert the [Carleman matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix) corresponding to the function:

```
CarlemanMatrix[f_, {x_, x0_, {m_Integer, n_Integer}}] := 
 Prepend[Table[
  If[k == 0, Function[x, f][x0]^j, 
   BellY[Table[{FactorialPower[j, i]
         Which[#2 == 0, 1, #1 == 0, 0, True, #1^#2] &[Function[x, f][x0], j - i], 
         Derivative[i][Function[x, f]][x0]}, {i, k}]]/k!],
                {j, m}, {k, 0, n}], UnitVector[n + 1, 1]]

CarlemanMatrix[f_, {x_, x0_, m_Integer}] := CarlemanMatrix[f, {x, x0, {m, m}}]
```

Here's how to apply this to your example:

```
coeffs = Inverse[CarlemanMatrix[ArcTan[Log[1 + x]/(1 + x)], {x, 0, 7}]][[2]]
{0, 1, 3/2, 3, 149/24, 68/5, 1481/48, 3241/45}

Normal[InverseSeries[Series[ArcTan[Log[1 + x]/(1 + x)], {x, 0, 7}]]]
x + (3*x^2)/2 + 3*x^3 + (149*x^4)/24 + (68*x^5)/5 + (1481*x^6)/48 + (3241*x^7)/45
```

There are other, likely more efficient methods for generating the coefficients of the inverse series (like the one I presented [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/57824)), but the Carleman approach offers flexibility, in that appropriate powers of the matrix give the coefficients of the corresponding iterate; e.g. the square of the Carleman matrix for $f(x)$ gives the coefficients of $f(f(x))$, and as you have seen here, inverting the Carleman matrix for $f(x)$ yields coefficients for $f^{(-1)}(x)$.

Comment: good idea. had never heard of a carleman matrix, thanks

Comment: Really interesting ! Thank you.